# MS SQL insert into auto increment column default value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a database interface to make some basic operations on tables.

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(20)
)
```

As long as I have been using MySQL database, it worked correctly to insert DEFAULT value onto 'ID' column

```
INSERT INTO products (ID, Name) VALUES (DEFAULT, "ProductName")
```

But MS SQL won't let me do that, the error I get is `DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.`.

I have been looking for solutions and couldn't find one - is there a way to include `ID` in the list of columns in the insert statement, but actually let the database handle the value to be inserted(auto-increment value)?

The answer to just not include `ID` in the list of columns is not solving my problem, as I access the database from a C++ program and try to do it as abstract as possible (and some different tables don't have auto-increment on ID)

Comment: afaik in SQL Server you do *not* include identity columns in an insert, unless you explicitely set `identity insert on`

Comment: Yes I know but I am looking for any work-around(if there is), as I wish to not implement different classes for MS SQL and MySQL, and also a different list of columns for insert, update etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I think a workaround would have to be in the application, not SQL Server. Possibly you could insert into a staging table that has a trigger to insert into the target table - but even if that could work it sounds ugly.

Comment: I have just found an @@identity function. What works so far is INSERT INTO products(@@identity+1, "name"), the only problem is that it seems like not working in MySQL(there's also @@identity, but it seems like not incrementing itself), but at least there's a solution to just print either DEFAULT or @@identity+1 depending on the database, without the need to replace logic. Could it be a good solution, or there are some drawbacks?

Comment: I can't change my comment, there's a mistake, this command works: `INSERT INTO products(ID, NAME) VALUES (@@identity+1, "name")` with setting `IDENTITY_INSERT` to ON

Comment: `@@identity` returns the last value inserted for all users - I wasn't aware you can use this in the way you describe - when I test on a table with an Identity I get the expected *Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table*

Comment: @Stu That's true it won't work as it will catch with other tables, but at least it is closer to a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure that sounds like a solution tbh, I would suspect you're likely to run into concurrency issues.

Comment: Might this be an [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/)? You mentioned that you don't want to "implement different classes for MS SQL and MySQL", but can't you handle that polymorphically? Have a class that implements all the common functionality, and then derive two types from that class, one for SQL, one for MySQL, with different implementations for just those features that need them. Or use dependency injection to inject an implementation class into an "interface" class.

Comment: @allmhuran yes, I believe it was an XY problem. I have solved it by removing the corresponding column and value on an index where value was equal to "AUTO", and so both MySQL and MS SQL works properly. However, I will not close this question as I believe it will be useful if somebody found a way to do it: put a value under a column, so the query will act as no column nor value is there.

Answer (score 1):

Two solution :

1. ignore the ID column in the column list :

   INSERT INTO products (Name) VALUES ('ProductName');
2. do not specify the column list if you want to insert in all columns except identity :

   INSERT INTO products VALUES (DEFAULT, ProductName);

By the way, double quote must never be used for strings but only simple quote. Double quote is reserved for "abnormal" objest names...

Answer (score 0):

You must be define the Id column like this:

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

Comment: The problem stays the same: `DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity value`

Comment: An IDENTITY field is an automaticaly auto increment column, why you would to set it whit a default value ? what is your goal ?

Comment: My goal is to make a common interface for all the tables, let's say I have a table where primary key IS NOT an auto-increment, so somebody writes in code `tableWithProducts.addRow({"MyPrimaryKey", "MyName"});`, however - there is a second table with auto-increment on first column, so I would let him write `tableWithProductsAuto.addRow({"DEFAULT","MyNameInSecondTable"});` with some mapping of DEFAULT to database 'default' keyword

Comment: In MySQL `DEFAULT` for identity column stands for next identity value, so it is just as inserting without the column name and without the value. And that's what I am trying to achieve

Comment: try INSERT INTO products (Name) VALUES ("ProductName")

Comment: _My goal is to make a common interface for all the tables_ Dream on - different database engines require different syntax and usage.